# Extract text between two strings repeatedly using sed or awk?

Tags: linux, sed, awk, grep, text-processing

I have a file called 'plainlinks' that looks like this:

```
13080. ftp://ftp3.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/noaa/999999-94092-2012.gz
13081. ftp://ftp3.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/noaa/999999-94094-2012.gz
13082. ftp://ftp3.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/noaa/999999-94096-2012.gz
13083. ftp://ftp3.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/noaa/999999-94097-2012.gz
13084. ftp://ftp3.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/noaa/999999-94098-2012.gz
13085. ftp://ftp3.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/noaa/999999-94644-2012.gz
13086. ftp://ftp3.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/noaa/999999-94645-2012.gz
13087. ftp://ftp3.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/noaa/999999-94995-2012.gz
13088. ftp://ftp3.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/noaa/999999-94996-2012.gz
13089. ftp://ftp3.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/noaa/999999-96404-2012.gz
```

I need to produce output that looks like this:

```
999999-94092
999999-94094
999999-94096
999999-94097
999999-94098
999999-94644
999999-94645
999999-94995
999999-94996
999999-96404
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using `sed`:

```
sed -E 's/.*\/(.*)-.*/\1/' plainlinks
```

Output:

```
999999-94092
999999-94094
999999-94096
999999-94097
999999-94098
999999-94644
999999-94645
999999-94995
999999-94996
999999-96404
```

To save the changes to the file use the `-i` option:

```
sed -Ei 's/.*\/(.*)-.*/\1/' plainlinks
```

Or to save to a new file then redirect:

```
sed -E 's/.*\/(.*)-.*/\1/' plainlinks > newfile.txt
```

Explanation:

```
s/    # subsitution
.*    # match anything
\/    # upto the last forward-slash (escaped to not confused a sed)
(.*)  # anything after the last forward-slash (captured in brackets)
-     # upto a hypen
.*    # anything else left on line
/     # end match; start replace 
\1    # the value captured in the first (only) set of brackets
/     # end
```

Answer (score 7):

Just for fun.

`awk -F\/ '{print substr($7,0,12)}' plainlinks`

or with `grep`

`grep  -Eo '[0-9]{6}-[0-9]{5}' plainlinks`

Comment: +1 for simpler grep solution.

Comment: @sudo_o well thanks, +1 for your solution. for being first.

Comment: agreed, +1 for the elegant grep solution

Comment: @sampson-chen, ok, +1 for you too.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the format stays consistent as you have described, you can do it with `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="[/-]"; OFS="-"} {print $7, $8}' plainlinks > output_file
```

Output:

```
999999-94092
999999-94094
999999-94096
999999-94097
999999-94098
999999-94644
999999-94645
999999-94995
999999-94996
999999-96404
```

**Explanation**:

- `awk` reads your input file one line at a time, breaking each line into "fields"
- `'BEGIN{FS="[/-]"; OFS="-"}` specifies that delimiter used on the input lines should be either `/` or `-`, it also specifies that the output should be delimited by `-`
- `{print $7, $8}'` tells awk to print the 7th and 8th field of each line, in this case `999999` and `9xxxx`
- `plainlinks` is the where the name of the input file would go
- `> output_file` redirects output to a file named `output_file`

Answer (score 4):

Just with the shell's parameter expansion:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    tmp=${line##*noaa/}
    echo ${tmp%-????.gz}
done < plainlinks
```

Answer (score 1):

If the format stays the same, no need for sed or awk:

```
cat your_file | cut -d "/" -f 7- | cut -d "-" -f 1,2
```

Comment: If the format doesn't stay the same, the sed and awk solutions will break just as much as this. :)