# Extract data between two strings using either AWK or SED

Tags: sed, awk

I'm trying to extract data/urls (in this case - **someurl**) from a file that contains them  within some tag ie.

```
xyz>someurl>xyz
```

I don't mind using either `awk` or `sed`.

Comment: Likely same as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13386080/extract-text-between-two-strings-repeatedly-awk-sed, although the example there is ugly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use sed/grep to extract text between two words?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13242469/how-to-use-sed-grep-to-extract-text-between-two-words)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the best, easiest, way is with `cut`:

```
$ echo "xyz>someurl>xyz" | cut -d'>' -f2
someurl
```

With `awk` can be done like:

```
$ echo "xyz>someurl>xyz" | awk  'BEGIN { FS = ">" } ; { print $2 }'
someurl
```

And with `sed` is a little bit more tricky:

```
$ echo "xyz>someurl>xyz" | sed 's/\(.*\)>\(.*\)>\(.*\)/\2/g'
someurl
```

we get blocks of `something1<something2<something3` and print the 2nd one.

Answer (score 0):

grep was born to extract things:

```
kent$  echo "xyz>someurl>xyz"|grep -Po '>\K[^>]*(?=>)'
someurl
```

you could kill a fly with a bomb of course:

```
kent$  echo "xyz>someurl>xyz"|awk -F\> '$0=$2'
someurl
```

Comment: Hi Kent, if you don't mind, could you explain '>\K[^>]*(?=>)'    
I'm assuming [^>] means the start and (?=>) as the end; what are the rest? thanks

Comment: `[^>]` means any char instead of `>` and `(?=>)` is look-ahead. matches char followed by `>`

Comment: awk is not a bomb, this is exactly what it is intended for.

Answer (score 0):

If your `grep` supports `P` option then you can use lookahead and lookbehind regular expression to identify the `url`.

```
$ echo "xyz>someurl>xyz" | grep -oP '(?<=xyz>).*(?=>xyz)'
someurl
```

This is just a sample to get you started not the final answer.